# SQL - Create multiple records from 1 record based on days between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, recursive-query

I have a table that holds an employee's leave. If an employee takes more than 1 day off in a row for example 22-05-2020 to the 26-05-2020 this will be displayed as one record. I am trying to get this displayed as 5 records, one for each day they were off.

My table is called: Emp_Annual_Leave
and has the following fields

```
emp_no      leave_type      leave_year      half_day    start_date  end_date    days_of_leave
12345       Annual          2020            N           22/05/2020  26/05/2020  5
```

above is how it is currently displayed and I am trying to display the above record like below:

```
emp_no  leave_type  leave_year  half_day    start_date  end_date    days_of_leave   leave_date
12345   Annual      2020        N           22/05/2020  26/05/2020  1               22/05/2020
12345   Annual      2020        N           22/05/2020  26/05/2020  1               23/05/2020
12345   Annual      2020        N           22/05/2020  26/05/2020  1               24/05/2020
12345   Annual      2020        N           22/05/2020  26/05/2020  1               25/05/2020
12345   Annual      2020        N           22/05/2020  26/05/2020  1               26/05/2020
```

Does anyone know I would go about doing this? I have a feeling I need to use ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY) but any attempts I have made haven't worked well for me.

Thanks in advance,

EDIT:
the table I need to create here is a subquery in a bigger query and needs to be joined back to other queries and tables in my DB. I didn't include this as part of my original question, updated to include now incase this impacts the methods I need to use

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using MicrosoftSQLServer2014

Comment: Are you looking for a quick answer or are you considering different approaches?

Comment: Ideally I need the table working for today as I need to rec it back to something before the DB updates on Monday, but it will be a long term solution so I will also need to consider different approaches and what works best for the DB. the above output I am looking for will actually need to be used as a subquery in my overall solution also, so I'm not sure if working with CTE's will work as a best solution for me (I also could be wrong here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select emp_no, leave_type, leave_year, half_day, start_date, end_date, days_of_leave, start_date as leave_date from emp_annual_leave 
    union all
    select emp_no, leave_type, leave_year, half_day, start_date, end_date, days_of_leave, dateadd(day, 1, leave_date)
    from cte
    where leave_date < end_date
)
select * from cte
```

If a given leave may span over more than 100 days, you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query.